# How can I exit (stop) my Dispatcher?

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

I would like to stop my dispatcher which has been started in the main(), when the user clicks a button.

```
    private void button_start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
            Camera.EventFrame -= onFrameEventFocusCam;  //unsubscribe event

            while (!Dispatcher.HasShutdownStarted)
            {
                // test if Dispatcher started shutdown  --> ok, it does but never finishs...!
            }
        ...
    }        


    private void onFrameEventFocusCam(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       ...

        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            // Convert bitmap to WPF-Image
            var bmp = new Bitmap(bitmap);
            var hBitmap = bmp.GetHbitmap();

            System.Windows.Media.ImageSource wpfBitmap = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            hBitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            image_fokus.Source = wpfBitmap;
            image_fokus.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.UniformToFill;


            DeleteObject(hBitmap);
            bitmap.Dispose();

        }));
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

When I run this code I get following error message while it is stopped in the `onFrameEventFocusCam`:

```
  Error-Message: Thread was interrupted from a waiting state.
```

Comment: If you stop the main thread dispatcher, the app will stop working... is it really what you want? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I don't like to stop the main thread. What I am trying to do is to stop a camera to show a live image. The application should still run.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `BeginInvokeDispatcher`, it causes the dispatcher to shut down *asynchronously*; it still needs to finish processing the current dispatcher frame before it shuts down. But since you're waiting in a loop for the dispatcher to shut down, the current frame never completes, so the dispatcher can't complete the shutdown. Instead, you can subscribe to the `ShutdownFinished` event to detect when the dispatcher shuts down.

As for the error you're getting in `onFrameEventFocusCam`, I think this is because the dispatcher is shutting down, so it can't process the `Invoke`; from the documentation:

> Once the shutdown process begins, all pending work items in the queue are aborted.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but shutting down the main dispatcher is very probably *not* the way to do it, as it will effectively stop the app...

Comment: I changed the code in the way that I am using this:            `Camera.EventFrame -= onFrameEventFocusCam;
Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();`

Now the shutdown process started but does not finish yet. So do I need to wait in a ShutdownFinished-Event until it is done?

Comment: @Norick, don't shutdown the dispatcher. It doesn't do what you want, it just stops the app. Unsubscribing from the event should be enough to stop displaying the images.

Comment: I unsubscribed from the event but I still get the same error message. If I also shutdown the dispatcher the app is still running but at least the event (almost) does not occur anymore. I do not fully understand why it does not work correctly...

Comment: @Norick, I can't tell without seeing more of your code... Is there a place in the code where you re-subscribe to the event?

Comment: You have been right the main thread will stopped as well when I shutdown the dispatcher - it only takes some time. I subscribe (once) to the event when I initialize the camera and unsubscribe once when I like to stop the event. Do I need to wait a certain time and introduce a Thread.Sleep(..)?

Comment: When I add 'Camera.EventFrame -= onFrameEventFocusCam;' once it works sometimes. Now I added it twice and it seems to work in the way I want. I do not understand why because the event is only subscribed once!

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you original intention was.

This code should hang (almost) forever because HasShutdownStarted doesn't become true until the application exits.

```
while (!Dispatcher.HasShutdownStarted)
            {
                // test if Dispatcher started shutdown  --> ok, it does but never finishs...!
            }
```

This code schedules execution of the delegate on the UI thread. Looks perfectly fine.

```
private void onFrameEventFocusCam(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       ...

        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
        ...
       }
    }
```

This code looks potentially problematic because if DeleteObject actually releases the handle, than the handle may be released twice, once in Delete and once in Dispose. This can throw.

```
DeleteObject(hBitmap);
bitmap.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

To make stop dispatcher running on your main application thread you should call return from action passed to Dispatcher.Invoke.

Comment: could you give an example please?